# Large scale volume lights

Tags: volumetrics

I'm setting up a large scale space scene, and trying to get some volumetric lights - like god rays. However when scaling up the volume cube, to sizes like 10,000 units the god rays disapear. I can only see either black volume, completely opaque or nothing, depending on the density. My light strength is already set to infinity.

I have a setup, with a spotlight, which works fine with cube of around 100 units size, but it's not working when scaled up ever 10x.

Any ideas ?

Thanks, 
Lukas

Comment: Which render are you using? Please add the correspodnding tag, e.g. 'Luxcore' 'Cycles' 'Eevee'

Answer (score 1):

An enlarged object set with volume scatter will seem denser, as the camera rays will need to traverse a larger space.
Make the lights brighter or bring down the density of the volume scatter and/or volume absorption.

As alternative use the world volume as domain instead of large volumes.

Another think to keep in mind is the camera clipping distance.  It is possible that if your lights fall outside the camera's clip distance they might have no effect at all.